# How to display a message in the login page when a user account is deactivated?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

what I would like to do is that when a user account is deactivated by an admin and the owner of the account esseye to connect with his account which is deactivated, an error message is displayed which indicates to him that his account is deactivated and it prevents him from connecting to the application.

this is my code .ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RestapiService } from 'src/app/restapi.service';
import { AuthServiceService } from 'src/app/auth-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  allUsers: any;
  username:string;
  password:string;
  message:any = ""
  msgDesactivation : any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service:RestapiService, private router:Router, private authService : AuthServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 

  doLogin() {
    this.service.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data=> {
      this.message = data;
      let role : string = this.authService.currentRole || '';
      role = role.toLowerCase().trim();
      
      switch(role){
        case "ad":
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/admin"]);
          break;
        case "drt":
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/directeur-affichage-menu-emploi"]);
          break;

        case "dev_w":
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/user"]);
          break;

        default:
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/user"]);

      }
      
    }, (error)=> {
      this.message = "User/password Inccorect";
    })

    if(this.allUsers.statut == "NV"){
      this.msgDesactivation ="Votre compte a été désactiver par un administrateur";
    }
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.service.getUsers().subscribe( 
      data => this.allUsers = data
    )
  }
}
```

here I put an authentication condition which tests if the login / password are correct or not and after I put if:

```
 if(this.allUsers.statut == "NV"){
      this.msgDesactivation ="Votre compte a été désactiver par un administrateur";
    }
```

which will test me if the status of my user is NV which means invalid or else VA which means valid, if it is NV then I must display a message that I store it in the msgDesactivation variable.

of course the status I retrieve it with the database that's why I created a service and I called it here in my .ts as you can see here:

```
getUsers() {
    this.service.getUsers().subscribe( 
      data => this.allUsers = data
    )
  }
```

and this is my html page :

```
<div class=background>
<div class="cnx">
  <!-- Default form login -->
  <form class="text-center  p-5">

    <p class="h4 mb-4">Authentification</p>
    <h3 *ngIf="!!message" class="alert alert-danger">{{message}}</h3>
    <!-- <h3 *ngIf="allUsers.statut" class="alert alert-danger">Votre compte a été désactivé par un administrateur</h3> -->
    <h3 *ngIf="!!msgDesactivation" class="alert alert-danger"> {{msgDesactivation}}</h3>
    <!-- Email -->
    <input type="text" id="defaultLoginFormEmail" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Login" name="login" [(ngModel)]="username">

    <!-- Password -->
    <input type="password" id="defaultLoginFormPassword" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
      
      <div>
        <!-- Forgot password -->
        <a routerLink="/forgot">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sign in button -->
    <button mdbBtn color="info" block="true" class="my-4" type="submit" id="btn-authentification" (click)="doLogin()">Se connecter</button>

   

  </form>
  <!-- Default form login -->

</div>
</div>
```

focus more on this code i put to display the error message i created in my .ts:

```
<h3 *ngIf="!!msgDesactivation" class="alert alert-danger"> {{msgDesactivation}}</h3>
```

can some one help me please ??

and thanks you very much for your answer in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the user is deactivated before logging in.

Call getUsers() in the ngOnInit and then

```js
  doLogin() {
     if(this.allUsers.statut == "NV"){
        this.msgDesactivation ="Votre compte a été désactiver par un administrateur";
       return;
     }

    this.service.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data=> {
      this.message = data;
      let role : string = this.authService.currentRole || '';
      role = role.toLowerCase().trim();
      
      switch(role){
        case "ad":
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/admin"]);
          break;
        case "drt":
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/directeur-affichage-menu-emploi"]);
          break;

        case "dev_w":
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/user"]);
          break;

        default:
          this.router.navigate(["home-component/user"]);

      }
      
    }, (error)=> {
      this.message = "User/password Inccorect";
    })

   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

RXJS can help you with that (need to know when developping in Angular)

Because you can use Observables, Subjects, BehaviorSubjects, pipes, combineLatest,...

this makes it easy to emit data streams to subscribers.

You're calling a backend service i suppose?
It would be eassier to provide a clear LoginResult that your service can return.

Then in your front end you can just read the resultCode for example and emit a new value for your msgDesactivation if the user is deactivated or not